# Prevent child from assuming full width of dynamic width parent

Tags: html, css

I have a container, and the width of this container is determined by either `max-width` or the `width` of its widest child.

[image]

How do I force each child to assume the width of its content while maintaining a single column of elements?

In the example below, how do I make the `abc` elements, outlined by the `limegreen` border, only as wide as their content (i.e. `abc`)?

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: solid orange 2px;
}

.child {
box-sizing: border-box;
border: solid limegreen 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child'>abcdefghi</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I misread the question.  inline-block indeed.

Comment: @TemaniAfif the problem with inline block is that i dont want them to be `inline`. i am trying to create one column of elements

Comment: display:table on each element will do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a flexbox layout will do the job

```css
#container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:flex-start; /* OR flex-end */
  border: solid orange 2px;
}

.child {
  border: solid limegreen 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child'>abcdefghi</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
</div>
```

Or `display:table` :

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid orange 2px;
}

.child {
  border: solid limegreen 2px;
  display:table;
  /* margin-left:auto to push to the right */
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child'>abcdefghi</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
</div>
```

Even float will do the job:

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid orange 2px;
}

.child {
  border: solid limegreen 2px;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  /* OR right for both */
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child'>abcdefghi</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: table` did the trick!! ill try `inline-flex` because i think thats more eloquent, but for some reason i have a feeling it will force the children to `100%` width

Comment: @oldboy you need to adjust the alignment in addition to inline-flex to avoid the shrink effect

Comment: jeez i missed all of these ways wow. i havent had to do something like this in ages. thank you sir

Comment: @oldboy also note that you can use float:right to put everything on the right and with the table solution you can add margin-left:auto to put everything on the right

Comment: yep! im already doing that `float: right; clear: right;` i think this is what i will probably use. the other answer is extremely eloquent `.child { width: fit-content }`, but it aligns everything to the left

Comment: its for an Electron app, so itll only ever be used on "chrome." but theres no point in using `fit-content` becuase i still have to position everything to the right. so far the shortest code solution is `float: right; clear: right;`

Comment: quick related question: how do i limit the height of a child of a flex-box to the height of its content?

Comment: youre rgiht sorry. i forgot i had padding :/

Answer (score 1):

Made `.child` `width: fit-content;`

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid orange 2px;
  direction: rtl;
}

.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid limegreen 2px;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child'>abcdefghi</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
  <div class='child'>abc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `inline-block` does not work in my case because then it forces the container to assume its `max-width` and positions everything in a row

Comment: @oldboy `inline-block` is from your code, I just added `width` property

Comment: is there an eloquent way to position them like `flex-end` that works with `fit-content`? `text-align: right` does not seem to work. if there is a way, ill def mark this as the answer because its a lot more eloquent

Comment: @oldboy `flexbox` is very convinient instrument, and I advise to use it for one one dementional layout, like in your case

Comment: yep `float: left/right; clear: left/right;` so far is the least amount of code to do this while also positioning them on the right side

Comment: @oldboy yes, `float: right` make the trick, but remember about `clear`, updated answer

Comment: if you use `float:right;clear:right`, then you dont even need to use `width:fit-content;`. anyways, thanks a lot for your help <3

Comment: @oldboy just FYI, recalled about `direction: rtl` property, you can add it to container and get the result, look in my answer.

Comment: wow very interested. im wondering if thatll conflict with other things tho? cuz isnt it a feature for text?

Comment: @oldboy The `direction` CSS property sets the direction of text, table columns, and horizontal overflow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction Imho the best way is to use  `flexbox` and this example more how esle could be done to get what you want.

Comment: flexbox is definitely a suitable approach, but `clear` and `float` is shorter